# Describe an atlas of smoothly related charts for the Special Orthogonal Group $SO(3)$

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology

The Special Orthogonal Group $SO(3) =$ {${A \in M_3(\mathbb{R}) : A^TA = I, det(A) = 1}$}

I have successfully shown that $SO(3)$ is a manifold, but I am having a difficult time explicitly finding a set of charts and their corresponding transition maps.

I understand that there is an [entire Wikipedia page on this topic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charts_on_SO(3)), but it's kind of overwhelming. I'm not sure where to begin and what the simplest method would be.

Comment: Start at the top of the page and keep going until you reach the bottom.

Comment: I'm not totally sure that this web page is very relevant for explicit atlas construction. Probably I would try to find an explicit diffeomorphism between $SO(3)$ and the real projective space $\Bbb RP^3$ where you have a standard atlas.

Comment: @PeterFranek Thanks! That makes since considering I demonstrated what the atlas was for $\mathbb{R}P^3$ on a previous problem.